# 为什么“道友”被译作“fellow cultivators”？

Tags: translation

[原作 《我被系统托管了》](https://read.qidian.com/chapter/jVvQ3swicPFxo3Pbs2jtrw2/14mBiRAuBJrgn4SMoDUcDQ2)
[译作 *Seized by the System*](https://www.webnovel.com/book/9795095706003005/26751469923386963/Seized-by-the-System/I%27ve-Been-Seized-by-the-System-)

> “各位**道友**请了，本座刚刚渡劫失败，先来地球歇歇脚。”
>
> "Greetings, **fellow cultivators**, I, the master, am just dropping by the
> Earth to rest after I failed some of God’s tests."

Looked up cultivator, I just found this [image]
I think it should be "fellow Taoism participators".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taoism has some mentions of the word "cultivation" (once in a title). So it might have its special use in Taoism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「道友」該釋爲「養道之友」，英語＂cultivate＂可翻譯成中文「養育」。

「道友」= "Fellows (友) who cultivate the way (養道)".

---

＂Cultivator＂也可翻譯成「耕田機」，因爲「耕田」在英文也可以叫＂cultivate＂，圖像由此意。

Comment: 道友-養道之友.以身飼道者!
讓人耳目一新啊!

Answer (score 1):

A cultivator can also mean a person or thing that cultivates(prepare the land) something, in this case, Taoism. So **fellow cultivator** is the suitable phrase here since everyone is a Taoism participator in the context of the book so don't need to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, in Hong Kong, 道友 typically means "drug addicts".

Answer (score 0):

用中文說中文
droooze說的不錯!這說法讓不才耳目一新!

### 道友:養道之友

道友:
同路人(志同道合者)
同志向者
有同一個夢想的人

道:道路
友:朋友

看到:"渡劫失败" 這關鍵字
聯想到玄幻小說
通常表示
有群人想追求長生,或跳脫輪迴,或者修仙!
基本上只要你會點法術或著有修行,甚至只要有修仙的心即可!
他們都會彼此稱呼為"道友"